# Rails 3 render partial without reloading images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, pjax

I have a view 'edit.html.erb' which renders a partial.

```
<div id="exerciseslist"><%= render 'exerciseslist' %></div>
```

Inside 'edit.js.erb', I have the following line which reloads the partial each time something is updated.

```
$('#exerciseslist').html('<%= escape_javascript(render("exerciseslist")) %>');
```

The partial is a table with a bunch of items including images for each one and some buttons. All that is changing in the partial is the button. If a submit is successful, the button toggles state indicating that it has been added.

It's working fine, the problem is I don't like the way the images flash as the request happens, the items are also inside a scrollable section which looses it's state each time.

Is there a good way to just load the state of the buttons without rendering the full partial? Or is there a simple way to stop the client requesting the images each time?

I have done some reading and found pjax and backbone.js, are either of them a good way or is there a simpler rails way to do this?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing code, it's hard to be sure, but I think it could be done with just Rails. Instead of re-rendering the `exerciseslist` partial on submission, you could write an AJAX request to handle submission of the new data and on success, have the callback change the button state, rather than reload the partial.